# jQuery: Height calculation for DIV fill remainder of viewport

Tags: jquery, height, viewport

I am trying to calculate the remaining height of the window, minus the height of all the other page elements, so that I can assign said height to a DIV. I think I have the structure correct, I'm just not sure about the syntax.

```
$('#container').height($(window).height() - $('#a, #b, #c, #d').height());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gtkgLem/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.height()` only gets the height of the first element in the set of elements you select. So you need to select each one separately and get it's height on its own.

From the docs:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
$('#container').height($(window).height() - $('#a').height() - $('#b').height() - $('#c').height() - $('#d').height());
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gtkgLem/2/

Comment: Thanks Jasper!
That works well! I forgot to accomodate margins, I assumed they would be included in the element height, but I guess not.

Now I'm dealing with this: https://jsfiddle.net/0gtkgLem/6/

Is it a more elegant solution, in your opinion, to switch to padding and solve the issue with CSS, or do it through jQuery?

Comment: @patrick Take a look at `.outerHeight(true)` for getting an element's height including padding and optionally margin: http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/. An updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gtkgLem/7/

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is correct. Your `jsfiddle` wasn't working because you weren't including the jQuery plugin. See https://jsfiddle.net/0gtkgLem/1/

Comment: You are right about the jsfiddle, but the height is still not correct. It's not making the div the exact height of the remaining space on the page. Its taller.

Comment: Is it perhaps the `#v`? That could be a typo